# Loop through each column and subtract another column in R

Tags: r, loops

Let's say I have a data frame with values from column 1-11.  For columns 1-10, I want to subtract column 11.  Basically I want dataframe[1]-dataframe[11], dataframe[2]-dataframe[11], dataframe[3]-dataframe[11], dataframe[n] - dataframe[11], etc...

So basically, in VBA terms, it would be like:

For each column in dataframe, starting with column 1, subtract column 11 from it.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `df[,1:10] = df[,1:10] - df[,11]`   No loops

Comment: omg ,this is perfec, thanks!  and here I am trying to use like lapply

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the subtraction directly.

```
df[,1:10] = df[,1:10] - df[,11]
```